# How to get an iframe inside tag "textarea" in webbrowser control c#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to get the complete iframe in textbox..

```
<textarea id="embed_code" spellcheck="false" onclick="this.select()" style="opacity: 1;">

   <iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="270" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x18adty"></iframe>

</textarea>
```

My code is as follows:

```
    HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    textBox5.Text = doc.GetElementById("video_title").InnerText;
    HtmlElement body = doc.GetElementById("embed_code");
    textBox3.Text = body.GetElementsByTagName("iframe").ToString();
```

Comment: Are you trying to show the iframe as text in the textarea? If so, html-escape it (most importantly transform `<` => `&lt;` )

Comment: I am trying to just copy this                                <iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="270" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x18adty"></iframe>         so that I can display it in my FORM textbox